# gensim document similarity: how to get document titles from most similar results?

Tags: python, nlp, similarity, gensim, lsa

I am using [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/index.html) to analyze document similarity in a large corpus. Each document has a "title", or more specifically, a unique ID string, along with the content text.

After looking through several [tutorials](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut3.html) about [top modeling](https://radimrehurek.com/topic_modeling_tutorial/2%20-%20Topic%20Modeling.html), [indexing and retrieval](https://radimrehurek.com/topic_modeling_tutorial/3%20-%20Indexing%20and%20Retrieval.html), and Wikipedia, what is still not clear to me is how to get interpretable results getting building the LSI model, and querying the index for some search vector. After I see the top N most similar document indexes and their similarity scores, how do I lookup the **titles** of those documents?

For example, in this [code](https://radimrehurek.com/topic_modeling_tutorial/3%20-%20Indexing%20and%20Retrieval.html):

```
index.num_best = 10
print(index[query_lsi])
INFO:gensim.utils:loading MatrixSimilarity object from ./data/wiki_index.0
INFO:gensim.utils:loading MatrixSimilarity object from ./data/wiki_index.1
INFO:gensim.utils:loading MatrixSimilarity object from ./data/wiki_index.2

[(4028, 0.82495784759521484), (52384, 0.82495784759521484), (13582, 0.8166358470916748), (61938, 0.8166358470916748), (0, 0.80658835172653198), (48356, 0.80658835172653198), (85, 0.8048851490020752), (48441, 0.8048851490020752), (115, 0.79446637630462646), (48471, 0.79446637630462646)]
```

How would I lookup the title of, for example, document #61938 that came back in the most similar results?

In the [previous part to that tutorial](https://radimrehurek.com/topic_modeling_tutorial/2%20-%20Topic%20Modeling.html), the `iter_wiki()` function yielded a tuple of the (title, tokens). That `title` is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The [second code](https://radimrehurek.com/topic_modeling_tutorial/3%20-%20Indexing%20and%20Retrieval.html) you posted uses only precomputed vectors and models (see `In[3]` and `In[4]` in same code). It doesn't use or store the documents or the titles as-is, and hence, it's not possible to retrieve the titles of the documents.

However, the [first code](https://radimrehurek.com/topic_modeling_tutorial/2%20-%20Topic%20Modeling.html) you posted defines and uses `WikiCorpus` class, which has a list called `titles`. You can simply use that list to retrieve the required titles.

So, basically this should work for you:
`wiki_corpus.titles[id]`